# Logfile for ruby bundler?

Tags: logging, ruby, bundle

I have got a ruby project defining a `Gemfile`. When I run `bundle update`, already installed *gems* are getting updated, probably, e.g.

```
    Installing rake 10.5.0 (was 10.4.2)
    Using CFPropertyList 2.2.8
    Using i18n 0.7.0
    Using json 1.8.3
    Using minitest 5.8.3
    Using thread_safe 0.3.5
    Using tzinfo 1.2.2
    Using activesupport 4.2.5
    Using addressable 2.4.0
    Installing ansi 1.5.0
    Installing ast 2.2.0 (was 2.1.0)
    Using parser 2.2.3.0
    Using astrolabe 1.3.1
    Using extlib 0.9.16
    [...]
```

Is there a logfile, to retrace/review what was happening during an update? A kind of `history.log` analog to what *apt* does.

Answer (score 0):

To review the version change of gem files, one could put `Gemfile.lock` under version control and diff revisions from before and after update.

I think, this is not applicable for new projects, that do not have a `Gemfile.lock` nor revision in a version control system, yet, and would require a `bundle install`.